# Banner size of 80px height is pixelated in android app

Tags: android, imageview, adbannerview

I am developing an app in which ,i'm in need to put a banner like in **NDTV and techcrunch** at the bottom of the app screen ,

Problem :

I have tried with the size 320 x 38 px which appears perfect. When I use a height greater than 38 it's pixelated and here is my code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listBanner"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/mobi" />
```

Could you please help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your scale type, resizes the image accordingly to the ImageView dimensions. If the w/h ration is not the same, the image will look pixelated.

Comment: @Lukas thanks for your reply,when i change both W /H of wrap_content for the scaleTYPE fitXY, the image is not pixelated but width i need to give fill_parent to occupy the screen width

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want to archive. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi @Lukas i don't have the permission to upload any image or screenshots and thing which i want is similar ad banner in NDTV

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use "fill_content" for your layout_width if you don't wan't to have a pixeliated image. If you do so and your image is not big enough, it will fill all the bottom width and pixelate it if it's not big enough.